# How can I run my async function in a for loop

Tags: node.js, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run an async function that send post request to the server and logs the response in the console. Whenever I run a for loop nothing is happening. I have checked a different similar questions here on stackoverflow but nothing is working in my case.

**Note** this code is for ionic + angular for android.

Below is the code for the function.

```js
postAPI(suffixUrl, queryString, data, header: any = {}) {
    // console.log(suffixUrl + "\n=>", queryString + "\n=>", data + "\n=>", header);
    this.isDisabled = true;

    data = (header.is == 'yes') ? JSON.parse(data) : data;

    let type = this.fileNameSubStringFn(suffixUrl, '?');
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.post(this.con.baseUrl + suffixUrl + queryString, data)
          .subscribe(res => {
            // res = res.json();
            // res = JSON.parse(res.data);
            console.log("RES:", res);
            this.hideLoader();
            resolve(this.data);
            return;
          }, (err) => {
            this.logFn("ERROR:" + JSON.stringify(err));
            this.isDisabled = false;
            // this.isConnected = false;
          });
    });
}
```

Below is the code that is accessing the above function in-order to submit the data.

```js
var i;

for (i = 0; i < summeriesArray.length; i++) {
    this.postAPI('service_summery', '', JSON.stringify(summeriesArray[i]), { is: 'yes', method: 'post' }).then(data => {
                this.hideLoader();
                this.toast("Successfully saved");
                console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Code inside `this.postAPI` is not executing which means the data is not being posted and I'm getting no errors so I don't know what is going on here.

I'm expecting the `this.postAPI` to run successfully in a for lop.

Thank you, posted with Love.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the await keyword, so you wait for the next iteration until the completion of the 'postAPI'.

```
for (i = 0; i < summeriesArray.length; i++) {
  const data = await this.postAPI('service_summery', '', JSON.stringify(summeriesArray[i]), { is: 'yes', method: 'post' })
  this.hideLoader();
  this.toast("Successfully saved");
  console.log(data);
}
```